# Out of index range error, a while loop containing list and dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

After finding an alternative solution to my previous problem, I have encountered a new one. I asked my teacher and he suggested that I use dict(zip) in this format.

```
final={}
rawLines=open("x.txt").readlines()
y=0
while y <5:
 for line in rawLines:
    userlist=rawLines[y].split(',')
    userid=userlist[0]
    avmph=userlist[1]
    print(avmph)
    #print(userid)
    for lines in rawLines[0:]:
        lines=lines[:-1]
        items=lines.split(',')
        final[items[0]]=dict(zip(userid,avmph))
 y=y+1
else:
 sorted[avmph()]
 print(avmph)
 print(userid)
```

I am getting an out of index range error with line. Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    userlist=rawLines[y].split(',')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have used a .txt file in the style of a .csv file which allows me to create lists. I eventually need to sort the average miles per hour and return the user ids alongside. My main problem seems to reside with 'y' variable and my while loop
(link to a screenshot of my .txt file)http://gyazo.com/ac8f734b9bb625398de6412191a64981

Comment: Aside: Good to know that you have learnt to post your attempt (unlike last time). However you need to include the full traceback of the error to help us debug.

Comment: Without the x.txt file and the traceback I don't think there's an answer.

Comment: Hint: `while y < 5` means that Y will iterate through lines 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. How many numbers is that, and how many lines does your input file have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

```python
y=0
while y < 5: print(y); y+=1
```

Then the output will be:

```python
0
1
2
3
4
```

& you file is only contains **4** lines. The **rawlines[y]**, where **y=4** tries to access the fifth line of the file. This gives this error. Replace the fourth line with **while y < 4** to fix it.